# How to print a array specific value from multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

Below is my array which i have printed:-

I want only the `product_image` from the array in loop

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_option_id] => 247
            [product_id] => 66
            [product_option_value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 42
                            [color_product_id] => 54
                            [name] => Pink
                            [product_image] => catalog/demo/teddy/03.jpg
                            [image] => http://192.168.15.9/Kids_stores/image/cache/catalog/axalta-ral-3015-light-pink-polyester-30-matt-powder-coating-20kg-box--1447-p-50x50.jpg
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 41
                            [color_product_id] => 67
                            [name] => Light Brown
                            [product_image] => catalog/Teddies/12-Baby-teddy/05.jpg
                            [image] => http://192.168.15.9/Kids_stores/image/cache/catalog/option-color/light_brown-50x50.jpg
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [product_option_value_id] => 43
                            [color_product_id] => 68
                            [name] => Cream 
                            [product_image] => catalog/Teddies/12-Baby-teddy/11.jpg
                            [image] => http://192.168.15.9/Kids_stores/image/cache/catalog/option-color/cream-images-50x50.jpg
                            [price] => 
                            [price_prefix] => +
                        )

                )

            [option_id] => 5
            [name] => COLOR
            [type] => image
            [value] => 
            [required] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: You can use `array_column()`. Using the `array_column()` you will get an array with the product images and then use them where you want. OR you can loop through this array and echo the product images directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for your edited input:-

```
$image_array = array();

foreach ($your_array as $arr){
   $image_array[] = array_column($arr['product_option_value'],'product_image');
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/657966

Comment: guyz sorry ..but onnce again i have edited the question please go through

Comment: It only prints array..nothing else

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
foreach($array as $val)
{ 
    echo $val['product_image'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the array [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and make it like this

```
$records = array (
     array ( 
              // your array
           )
);
$variable = array_column($records, 'image');
echo $variable;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php $samples=$data['options'][0][product_option_value]; 



    $product_image = array_column($samples, 'product_image');
    echo'<pre>'; print_r($product_image );  

    ?>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution One:**

```
<?php
$req_image=array();
$req_image[] = array_column($resultant_array, 'product_image');   
print_r($req_image); // This will print all the images that are grouped under the array().
?>
```

**Example:**

The below is the PHP code and the sample output that you can obtain using the `array_column()`.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe'
    )
);

$lastNames = array_column($records, 'last_name', 'id');
```

**Output:**

If we call `print_r()` on `$lastNames`, you’ll see a resulting array that looks a bit like this:

```
Array
(
    [2135] => Doe
    [3245] => Smith
    [5342] => Jones
    [5623] => Doe
)
```

**Solution Two: (*As per requirement at last*)**

You can iterate the single key value alone in the foreach so that you can get the required parameter that you need.

```
foreach($resultant_array as $single_array)
{
  foreach($single_array['product_option_value'] as $inner_array)
  {
    echo $inner_array['product_image']; // This will print the u=mage name that you need.
  }
}
```

Comment: @priyankasawant. Try this solution and share thoughts

Comment: this is printed Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: By using which one solution one r two.

Comment: Try using `array_column()`. It will help you a lot .

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: by two solution @naresh

Comment: Now try the second one @priyankasawant. I have removed the foreach loop.

Comment: Pass the array which you get into the `array_column()` and then try for your image name can be retrived.

Comment: @priyankasawant. I have provided a solution three you can obtain the result using that. I have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $val){
  if($key == 'product_image'){
    echo "<img src='".$val."' />";
  }
}
```

Try

Comment: when i print $data['options'];  the following result comes...So how should i use in above code

Comment: @priyankasawant  why don't you go with Frayen comeent. You can get easily what you want. That are mentioned in other answers too.

Comment: use $data['options'] instead of $array

Comment: @khaliq its not working..Array
(
    [product_option_id] => 227
    [product_id] => 54
    [product_option_value] => Array
        (
        )

    [option_id] => 11
    [name] => Size
    [type] => select
    [value] => 
    [required] => 1
)

Comment: Place an array in a variable and then pass it into foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to foreach the inner array:

```
foreach($array[product_option_value] as $val)
{ 
    echo $val['product_image'];
}
```

Comment: what I can place in $array @igor unger

Comment: I assumed that you will use the array in your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want one specified key and want minimal assumptions about array structure shoud use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) like this

```
 $result = []; 
 array_walk_recursive($input,function ($value,$key) use (&$result) {
           if ( 'product_image' == $key) {
               $result[] = $value;
           }
 });
```